# Dialogflow - Using RegEx Entity with other entity in Traning Phrase gives empty value for the parameter

Tags: regex, dialogflow-es

I am using a Regular Expression for the date format (DD/MM/YYYY) validation. If I have the training phrase as `22/05/2021` it works perfectly.

But I need to have the training phrase as `22/05/2021 sample@sample.com`. When I use like that for the date it gives empty value as shown in the below image.

[image]

if I use @sys.date for the date field it not always gives the correct format I need.

As an example, if I need the value `3rd of June, 2021` and enter it as `03/06/2021`, Dialogflow evaluates it as `2001-03-06` (6th of March, 2021). But I need it as `03/06/2021`

The locale I have to use with my agent is English-en

**Updated**

Not even for date validation, this is not working for any regular expression combined with email as in the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What pattern do you use?

Comment: Regular Expression used for @mydate is (^(((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])[\/](0[1-9]|1[012]))|((29|30|31)[\/](0[13578]|1[02]))|((29|30)[\/](0[4,6,9]|11)))[\/](19|[2-9][0-9])\d\d$)|(^29[\/]02[\/](19|[2-9][0-9])(00|04|08|12|16|20|24|28|32|36|40|44|48|52|56|60|64|68|72|76|80|84|88|92|96)$)  I guess it is not working with for any pattern like myDigit=^[0-9]$, (updated the question.)